# Tailwindcss Default CSS Utility BackgroundColor Not Taking Affect For Responsive Display

Tags: reactjs, next.js, responsive, tailwind-css

I have a background color that should take place by default, no matter what the view size is. However, it is only taking affect once the view size exceeds lg.

I have upgraded to the latest version of Tailwindcss & NextJs, as well as verified the tailwind config.

Not sure what I am missing, any insight would be appreciated.

Here is the div. The utility class is bg-secondary, which should display the defined background color on all sizes, but is only displaying on LG.

```
<div className=" w-full flex absolute bg-secondary lg:bg-white opacity-70 sm:p-4 md:p-14 lg:p-24 lg:top-2/3 lg:left-30">
      &nbsp;
</div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could it be just not visible when the left and top are not set?

Comment: Thank you, that was it!  I will need to add the corresponding alignments for the smaller views.

Answer (score 0):

You set the following classes for background color:

```
sm:bg-secondary lg:bg-white
```

Which means that the background of your div will be of "secondary" color when the viewport is larger then `sm` and when the viewport is larger then `lg` it will be white. Below `sm` no background color will be applied.

If you want it, as you state, to

> display the defined background color on all sizes

Then you need to just use the class `bg-secondary` nothing else

Comment: Thanks, for your response... but changing to bg-secondary does  not work, I have tried that.  When the viewport is changed to be something like: md, there is now bg color .... If i remove the lg & sm and have only bg-secondary, it works as expected. But if i add lg:bg-white, it does not.